# Aligning collapsible buttons in Twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]I have made a 2 buttons on the same line . The second is a collapsible button which adds a row of 2 more buttons to the view . All this works fine .

However the newly collapsed row of buttons is aligned with the second button . I would like it to re-allign it in the newly collapsed line . How is that possible?

```
<div class="span5 offset4">
    <button class="btn-primary btn-large btn-bank" type="button"
        style="width: 100%;">Big Button </button>
</div>

<div id="collapsabilebutton">
    <a href="#show" data-toggle="collapse"><button
    class="btn btn-large">
    Button just next to Big button . Click it to expand a new row of buttons . 
    </button></a>
</div>

<div id="show" class="collapse">
    <button class="btn btn-small">hi</button>
    <button class="btn btn-small">hi</button>
</div>
```

My need : I dont want the new row to be left alligned with the small button above it . In fact i want it to be alligned with the Big button instead .

Any ideas ?

**EDIT 1 :** Bootstrap version 2.3

**EDIT 2 :** Added Image since its tough to re-create the fiddle exactly.

I want to place the `Hi` button not exactly below the `Click Me` button but allign it with the `Big Button` .

```
**EDIT 3 ( Answer )**
```

The solution  was pretty simple in fact . The collapsible buttons should be placed within the div tags of the parent to which the alignments must be made ! Hence changed the code to the following and it works :

```
   <div class="row">
    <div class="span5 offset4">
        <button class="btn-primary btn-large btn-primary" type="button"
            style="width: 100%;">Large Button</button>
            <div id="show" class="collapse">
                <button class="btn btn-small">hi</button>
                <button class="btn btn-small">hi</button>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapsabilebutton">
        <a href="#show" data-toggle="collapse"><button
            class="btn btn-large">Click</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it would be best if you can show in fiddle how it currently looks and what exactly you want to achieve in visuals. :)

Comment: I tried making a fiddle out of it . http://jsfiddle.net/cDyHz/2/ But besides using the Bootstrap js i also need to use Bootstrap.dropdown.js . I cant find a way to link my fiddle to it . Hence i am unable to show it properly :(

Comment: Basically what i want is `Big Button` & `Click Me` on the same line . Upon Clicking on Click Me the button collapses to show `Hi` button . However the `HI` button should be not immediately below the `Click Me` button but i want the flexibility of placing it anywhere on the line containing the button . I tried using span , offset but using it makes the `Hi` button no longer collapsible but visible all the time :(

Comment: Here is your jfiddle with twitter bootstrap 2.3.2 (you might want to specify the version as well in your case since bootstrap 3.0 is out): http://jsfiddle.net/cDyHz/3/

Comment: I still use the old bootstrap . yes i shall update my version .

Comment: I'm afraid it won't be as straightforward as it is. Your easiest way out is to use jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I am trying not to affect your current code too much, so I just added one css modification:

```
div#show {
    width: 100%;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cDyHz/4/

Comment: Thanks this is a really good suggestion Especially if the parent div is at the leftmost on the line . I drew inspiration from this and fixed my problem . Basically I need to place my collapsible div within the parent div :-) thats it . thanks for your suggestions .